# Meteor - Autoform with Meteor.users collection

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Creating a little test with Autoform and Meteor.users. If I create my own collection, it's fine. But somehow with I keep getting this error and I have no clue what's wrong..

error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
14autoform-inputs.js:162 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formValues' of undefined
```

template:

```
    {{> loginButtons}}

    <div class="container">
        <h2>update</h2>
        {{> update }}
    </div>  
</body>

<template name="update">
  {{> quickForm collection="Meteor.users" 
                id="update-user-profile" 
                type="update" 
                doc="user"
            }}
</template>
```

scheme with helper returning the current user:

```
Meteor.users.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    country: {
        type: String,
        label: "Country"
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        label: "city"
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        label: "email"
    },
    story: {
        type: String,
        label: "your story",
        optional: true,
        max: 1000
    }
}));

if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.update.helpers({
        user: function(){
            return Meteor.userId();
        }
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the quotes for user

Change `doc="user"` to `doc=user`

Your template should look like this

```
<template name="update">
  {{> quickForm collection="Meteor.users" 
                id="update-user-profile" 
                type="update" 
                doc=user
            }}
</template>
```

Check out this [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/pzeMdN2HpWLm5YxL2/Meteor%20-%20Autoform%20with%20Meteor.users%20collection)

Comment: hey thanks for your answer and the link, but I don't see a working version running in MEteorPad, actually I'm seeing nothing and refreshing (both browser or pad itself) doesn't work. Are you sure that's correct? Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong here